# Entity Framework 6 with Database-First Many to Many relationship problem

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm having a bit of a problem with EF 6 DB first using a many-to-many relationship schema.
Here's an simplified example:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public partial class Car
{
    public Car()
    {
        this.People = new HashSet<Person>();
        this.Tires = new HashSet<Tire>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Model{ get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tire> Tires { get; set; }
}

public partial class Tire
{
    public Tire()
    {
        this.Cars = new HashSet<Car>();
    }

    public string Model{ get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars{ get; set; }
}
```

There are five tables in the DB for this:

**Person**
**PersonCarMapping**
**Car**
**CarTireMapping**
**Tire**

Three tables to store data and two tables to map/associate the data.
My problem happens when I create a Person object, populate it with data, and try to save it.

A person might have multiple cars and a car might have different model tires, hence the many-to-many mapping.
If I create a Person object, with multiple cars, BUT with several of those cars having the same Model tire (the PK of the Tire table), EF doesn't check first to see if that Tire model is already a part of this Person object (by association), and it tries to add it two or more times to the Tire table.  In reality, only the mapping table needed to be modified to show a new mapping between Car and (already existing) Tire.

So after building a Person object, with multiple cars, cars with multiple tires, etc. and trying:

```
context.Person.Add(personObject)
context.SaveChanges();
```

Gives a primary key violation error on the Tire table.  What am I missing?
EF seems to handle deletes OK by only deleting from the mapping tables but additions are giving me problems.

[edit]
I'm going to switch this up a bit because I found a solution for my original issue but a similar one popped up.

Here's how I would build a couple of person objects:

```
Person p1 = new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Joe" }
Car car1 = new Car() { Id = 1, Make = "Honda", Model = "Accord" } 
Car car2 = new Car() { Id = 2, Make = "Honda", Model = "Civic" }
Tire tire1 = new Tire() { Model = "ModelA", Size = 16 }
car1.Tires.Add(tire1);
p1.Cars.Add(car1);
p1.Cars.Add(car2);

Person p2 = new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "Bob" }
Car car3 = new Car() { Id = 1, Make = "Honda", Model = "Accord" } 
p1.Cars.Add(car3);

// Finally
context.Person.Add(p1);
context.SaveChanges();   // Necessary to save twice.  Don't ask.

context.Person.Add(p2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This throws a primary key violation because it tries to add a Car of Id 1   when saving p2.  Is there a way to make EF smart enough to realize that only   the association table needs to be added to and that the Car table itself   doesn't need to be touched because a Car with ID 1 already exists in the Car   table?

Comment: Looks like you have to attach some tires to the context before adding the person, but it's hard to tell without seeing the contents of `personObject`.

Comment: I think he sample code has an error (you probably mean  `p2.Cars.Add(car3);`) , but basically you shouldn't instantiate 2 cars with the same `Id`. Which means: do `p2.Cars.Add(car1);`. No need to call `SaveChanges` twice.

Comment: In short: populate a graph respecting *identity resolution* and attach to the context as Unchanged (or maybe Modified) what shouldn't be saved as new. Only then `Add` the graph root.

Comment: You are correct and I made the edit.  I was coming to the same conclusion as you: that EF requires each object to be distinct at the object level.  I, incorrectly, assumed that EF would have some kind of "InsertIfNotExists" method, which would make my life alot simpler.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the entity state before calling SaveChanges .

```
context.Entry(existingCar).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Comment: I completely built this example from scratch and it shouldn't be taken literally.   I just wanted something to illustrate my problem.  It's a database first EF creation and according to the database designer, the foreign keys and primary keys were detected properly.

Comment: I want to see how  you are building a Person object? are you creating new Tire object when building Person object ?

Comment: I'll add to the original question

Comment: in your question you said "Tire model is already a part of this Person object (by association)",. if you will use new Tire then it will create new record in table  and if you want to use existing then first get the tire object and use that object when creating the Person object .

Answer (score 0):

EF deals with references. Two different references to an object with the same key are not treated as the same thing:

```
Person p1 = new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Joe" }
Car car1 = new Car() { Id = 1, Make = "Honda", Model = "Accord" } 
p1.Cars.Add(car1);

Person p2 = new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "Bob" }
Car car3 = new Car() { Id = 1, Make = "Honda", Model = "Accord" } 
p2.Cars.Add(car3);
```

Car 1 & 3 are two separate references but meant to point at car ID=1. I think you had a bug in your example which had `p1.Cars.Add(car3)` instead of p2. Either way, the issue is with the two car instances. Instead:

```
Person p2 = new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "Bob" }
p2.Cars.Add(car1);
```

Now car ID 1 will be correctly referenced between Person 1 and Person 2.